# Global Temp table fusing on Tomee before session close

Tags: java, spring, oracle11g, apache-tomee

We have an ui application. one of the functionality is, when user search for something, we store search result on temp table and then show data to user. Upon user submit his change and submit. somehow, temp table is not having search result before saving to database. Database using is oracle.

This functionality recently moved from web logic to tomee. It was perfectly fine with weblogic. No code changes between weblogic and tomee.

Any idea why global temp table data flushing on same active session and how to make it work on tomee.

Answer (score 0):

Comment you posted suggests that global temporary table was created with `on commit delete rows`.

Drop the table and create it so that it **preserves** rows on commit.

The way it is now, those rows are valid during current transaction so you don't have anything afterwards. If you preserve rows, they will be visible during the entire session.